# Не могу получить весь список отзывов из Android приложения

Tags: php, google-oauth2

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне получить список всех отзывов? Я запрашиваю отзывы о своем приложении, но мне возвращается только последний.

Для авторизации я создал аккаунт-сервер, дал прав на выпуск токена и чтение отзывов, загрузил файл `.json` и поместил его в корневую папку. Думаю, если бы что-то в этой части было некорректно, то я бы вообще не получал ошибку, но в моем случае приходит отзыв, но только 1, а нужен весь список отзывов.

Код вызова:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
define('PACKAGE_NAME', 'spain.barcelona.myapplication');   
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='.__DIR__.'/api-6154269159051481497-574099-e0b562752ef6.json');

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_AndroidPublisher::ANDROIDPUBLISHER);
$client->setAccessType("offline");

$service = new Google_Service_AndroidPublisher($client);
$response = $service->reviews->listReviews( PACKAGE_NAME );

echo "<pre>".print_r($response,true)."</pre>";
```

Ответ:

```
Google_Service_AndroidPublisher_ReviewsListResponse Object(
[collection_key:protected] => reviews
[pageInfoType:protected] => Google_Service_AndroidPublisher_PageInfo
[pageInfoDataType:protected] => 
[reviewsType:protected] => Google_Service_AndroidPublisher_Review
[reviewsDataType:protected] => array
[tokenPaginationType:protected] => Google_Service_AndroidPublisher_TokenPagination
[tokenPaginationDataType:protected] => 
[internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
(
)
[modelData:protected] => Array
(
)
[processed:protected] => Array
(
)
[reviews] => Array
(
    [0] => Google_Service_AndroidPublisher_Review Object
        (
            [collection_key:protected] => comments
            [authorName] => Natik Abasov
            [commentsType:protected] => Google_Service_AndroidPublisher_Comment
            [commentsDataType:protected] => array
            [reviewId] => gp:AOqpTOESHBw_VPI7qg1p7PpjuZ8d9OIy35inocZlUZ_9npd1todn8SD9EyddObK9Jzw3vPVp81K1f_XUNCPldA
            [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
                (
                )
            [modelData:protected] => Array
                (
                )
            [processed:protected] => Array
                (
                )
            [comments] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Google_Service_AndroidPublisher_Comment Object
                        (
                            [developerCommentType:protected] => Google_Service_AndroidPublisher_DeveloperComment
                            [developerCommentDataType:protected] => 
                            [userCommentType:protected] => Google_Service_AndroidPublisher_UserComment
                            [userCommentDataType:protected] => 
                            [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )
                            [modelData:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )
                            [processed:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [developerComment] => 1
                                )

                            [userComment] => Google_Service_AndroidPublisher_UserComment Object
                                (
                                    [androidOsVersion] => 
                                    [appVersionCode] => 16
                                    [appVersionName] => 16.0
                                    [device] => beryllium
                                    [deviceMetadataType:protected] => Google_Service_AndroidPublisher_DeviceMetadata
                                    [deviceMetadataDataType:protected] => 
                                    [lastModifiedType:protected] => Google_Service_AndroidPublisher_Timestamp
                                    [lastModifiedDataType:protected] => 
                                    [originalText] => 
                                    [reviewerLanguage] => ru
                                    [starRating] => 5
                                    [text] =>   Great!
                                    [thumbsDownCount] => 
                                    [thumbsUpCount] => 
                                    [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )[modelData:protected] => Array()
                                    [processed:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )
                                    [lastModified] => Google_Service_AndroidPublisher_Timestamp Object
                                        (
                                            [nanos] => 270000000
                                            [seconds] => 1596617390
                                            [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                            [modelData:protected] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                            [processed:protected] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                        )
                                    [deviceMetadata] => Google_Service_AndroidPublisher_DeviceMetadata Object
                                        (
                                            [cpuMake] => Qualcomm
                                            [cpuModel] => SDM845
                                            [deviceClass] => FORM_FACTOR_PHONE
                                            [glEsVersion] => 
                                            [manufacturer] => Xiaomi
                                            [nativePlatform] => ABI_ARM64_V8,ABI_ARM_V7,ABI_ARM
                                            [productName] => beryllium (POCO F1)
                                            [ramMb] => 
                                            [screenDensityDpi] => 
                                            [screenHeightPx] => 
                                            [screenWidthPx] => 
                                            [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                            [modelData:protected] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                            [processed:protected] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
)
```

Comment: Вам лучше это спрашивать в поддержке Гугла. В [документации](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/androidpublisher/v3/php/latest/class-Google_Service_AndroidPublisher_Reviews_Resource.html) указано что извлекаются только отзывы за предыдущую неделю.